# zsh parameter expansion flag (P) with associative arrays

Tags: zsh, associative-array

In the zshexpn manual page (zsh version 5.1.1) we have:

> **Parameter Expansion Flags**
>
> (P): This forces the value of the parameter name to be interpreted as a  further parameter name, whose value will be used where appropriate. *Note that flags set with one of the typeset family  of commands (in particular case transformations) are not applied to the value of name used in this fashion.*

So, if I have a regular array parameter, I can do this:

```
typeset -a array
array=(x y)

ptr=array
echo ${${(P)ptr}[1]}
```

and this will output `x`. I presume this is because the `-a` typeset flag is not necessary to mark the parameter as an array.

But if I do the same with an associative array:

```
typeset -A assoc
assoc=(foo x bar y)

ptr=assoc
echo ${${(P)ptr}[foo]}
```

nothing is printed to the screen. This appears consistent with the man page message above because if we run:

```
echo ${(P)ptr}
# returns: x y
echo ${${(P)ptr}[1]}
# returns: x
echo ${${(P)ptr}[2]}
# returns: y
```

we get behaviour as if the the `-A` flag to `typeset` was discarded, and we have a normal array.

But if I run the following:

```
echo ${(Pk)ptr}
# returns: foo bar
echo ${(Pv)ptr}
# returns: x y
echo ${(Pkv)ptr}
# returns: foo x bar y
```

then it seems as if in some sense the associative array status is not always lost. So I don't really understand why it was designed so that `typeset` flags are discarded, when it looks like they don't always do this anyway.

And, mainly, my question is this: is there some way to make this:

```
echo ${${(P)ptr}[foo]}
```

return `x` (the value associated to the key `foo`) as if the `typeset -A` flag were not discarded, and I can treat it like any other associative array. I would like to *not* resort to using `eval`s: is there some zsh parameter trickery that I can use instead?

Comment: Work well with `zsh 5.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)`

Comment: Really? The documentation online for [version 5.3.1](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) still indicates that `typeset` flags would be discarded. Perhaps the documentation is not up to date? Or apple have modified the source code? (Although that seems less likely, here.)

Comment: There have been some changes around http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2015/msg03029.html

Comment: http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2015/msg03006.html is the change that fixed it (5.1.1-test-1 and above).